# Is there a name for formulae that are true independent of domain?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

First-order formulae which are true under any interpretation are known as *valid formulae*.

I am curious to know if there is a name given to those formulae which are true under any domain of discourse, but whose truth is dependent on its component predicates.  For instance, consider the predicates:

$D(x) =$ '$x$ is a dog' 
$M(x) =$ '$x$ is a mammal'

The formula $\forall x(D(x) \to M(x))$ would be an example of such a formula, because it is true under any domain of discourse, but only because of the choice of the predicates D and M, so it's certainly not a valid formula.

Comment: But the formula  $∀x(D(x)→M(x))$ is not the sentence: "every dog is a mammal". The first one can be interpreted differently in different contexts (universes) while the second not.

Comment: The philosophical traditionn call such statements [Analytic truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analytic-synthetic/).

Comment: I don't understand your first comment.  Why would this not translate to 'every dog is a mammal', and what do you mean by first and second?

Comment: The formula $∀x(D(x)→M(x))$ is a formula, and thus can be interpreted in many ways: as "every dog is a mammal" and as "every even is a multiple of two".

Comment: Alternatively, we can say that the formula is *valid* (i.e. *necessaruly true*), restricting the definition of *logically valid* to formulas like: $\forall x (D(x) \lor \lnot D(x))$.